# open the downloaded file in new tab

Tags: php, html, download, meta-tags

in my web page i used

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="3;URL=<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>/images/uploads/<?php echo $filee;?> " target="_blank">
```

to download files. it works well but the PDF and image files are opening in the current tab. is there any way to make them open in new tab in the browser.

(I used header for making file download but since it is a force download it will not print some text before downloading. that is why I use meta for file download.)

Answer (score 0):

You should also send header (when you are trying to download files):

```
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
```

And all files will download, not show in browser.

Comment: thanks for ur response sir. but i cant use header function sir. because before downloading i need to change the page content to print a thanks message.if i use header it wont change the content and force user to download.thats why i use meta. :)